# How can I use reduceByKey from spark to sum integers in a list?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a (key, value) whose value is equal to a list of integers inside a list. I mean:

```
(Key, Value) = ("aaa", [ [1,2,3],[1,1,1] ])
```

I want reducebykey summing each value of the same position as below:

```
("aaa", [1+1,2+1,3+1])
```

What is the best way to do this using `reduceBykey` function?

Thank u!

Comment: For `[1,2,3],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]` will the output be `[1+1+2,2+1+2,3+1+2]` so the final output `[4,5,6]` ?

Comment: Below link can help you if it is converted to a DataFrame. https://github.com/gopal-tiwari/spark-array-sum-uadf

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure why you need to use reduceByKey here but providing my solution based on my understanding.

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
def col2sum(x:Array[Int],y:Array[Int]):Array[Int] = {
     x.zipAll(y,0,0).map(pair=>pair._1+pair._2)
}
val kvData = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("aaa", Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(1, 1, 1)))))
val output = kvData.map(data => (data._1, data._2.reduce(col2sum)))
```

Converting as DataFrame to check results:

```
output.toDF("field_1", "field_2").show()
+----+---------+
|ddff|    dffhj|
+----+---------+
| aaa|[2, 3, 4]|
+----+---------+
```